# Solving linear nonhomogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have to solve such an equation:
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime \prime}+\frac{\pi}{3}y^{\prime}+ay=b
\end{equation}
where $a$ and $b$ are constants. I can`t pick up a partial solution, so I hope for your help.

Comment: $y=\frac b a$ is a solution if $a \neq 0$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.